# Symfony set variable in session really slow

Tags: php, symfony, session

How come that setting a variable in my session is really really slow?

I have a voter which runs at every request (afaik). In this voter, I need to run a query to determine which custom roles my user has (defined in MySQL). So what I want to do, is save this data into my session, so I don't have to run this query on every request, which is really heavy.

So the code in my vote function:

```
$permissions = $this->context_manager->get('session')->get('permissions');
if (!$permissions) {
    $permissions = $this->entitymanager->findPermissions(User $user);
    $this->context_manager->get('session')->set('permissions', $permissions);
}
```

I debugged this (commenting every line, until I knew what was the problem) and it turned out that setting the variable in the session was really slow. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Is $permissions a plain array or DoctrineCollection of Entity objects?

Comment: @JurgisGregov plain array, contains around ~10 strings

Comment: What session storage are you using?

Comment: @JurgisGregov where can I find that?

Comment: dump(get_class($this->storage)); in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session::__construct

Comment: You can try with `$this->context_manager->get('session')->clear()` before setting the variable. If it works better, you are may abusing the session storage.

Comment: @Manolo my app fails when the session is cleared. So that's not working

Comment: @JurgisGregov I saw I was using the NativeSession. I now added the SncRedisBundle. But Symfony still says I'm using NativeSession.